# Sed command from command line into script

Tags: bash, sed

I want the string `index.xml` to be appended when I see something ending in `/feed/` and starting with `http://a.b.c`

Using the command line I wrote, and works, this

```
echo "http://a.b.c/blabla/feed/" | sed -e 's#\(http://a.b.c/.*/feed/\)#\1index.xml#g'
```

I don't know how to transform this code so that it works in a script using -i and a file as parameter.

I tried the following but it works only if the searched string is on a line alone, while I need to transform also strings between other text. What's the correct code?

```
#!/bin/bash

sed -i 's#\("http://a.b.c/.*/feed/"\)#"\1index.xml"#g' $1
```

Comment: `sed -i 's#http://a\.b\.c/.*/feed/#&index.xml#g' "$1"`

Comment: I tried this command but it does nothing

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: @Inian it's the GNU variant

Comment: Also why are you using `-i` if you are modifying an URL passed as an argument

Comment: @Inian I need to work on a file, the command line example is actually a bit different to what I wanted to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think

```
#!/bin/bash

sed -i 's#\(http://a.b.c/.*/feed/\)#\1index.xml#g' "$1"
```

should work.  I only removed the wrong double quotes in the command and added the missing ones around the `$1`.

If an input like `http://aXbXc/` is not supposed to trigger the replacement, then you should also escape the dots.

Comment: Unfortunately my and your command work on a small file I created as a sample and don't work on a real HTML file I have. I'll have to investigate further

Comment: Is it `https` maybe?

Comment: No, it's a simple local file

Comment: I meant, is the pattern you should be looking for maybe not starting with `http` but with `https`?  Does your file contain it with `https` maybe?  That's often overlooked.

Comment: I found out that sed wasn't working because of a minified file of 142kb. Disabling minifying made sed work! But I need minifying... Do you know anything about sed limitations related to file size?

Comment: You need to have a look at the result of the minifying.  It obviously changes your URL so that it isn't present anymore in the result.  Maybe it detects an often used common prefix and factorizes this out.  You need to find out more about the minifying result and its patterns.